# How do I select missing table rows belonging to Table A from Table B?

Tags: php, mysql

```
table1
id, name, desc

1, Abc, some desc
2, Def, more desc
4, Jkl, another desc

table2 
id, table1_id, title
1,  1, My title
2,  1, Another title
3,  3, Yet another title
```

Table 1 has row with id of 3 "missing". But if you notice, there is one refernece to this missing id in table2. So my question is how do I select all rows of table2 which has references to table1_id(s) which no longer are availabe in table1??

I am not very good at mysql queries and tried something like ... 
SELECT b.* FROM table2 b INNER JOIN table1 a ON b.table1_id != a.id and some others but could not get the desired result.

Could you throw some idea how this can be achieved? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT b.*
FROM table2 b
LEFT JOIN table1 a ON b.table1_id = a.id
WHERE a.id is null
```

Just some minor changes, from INNER to LEFT OUTER, with the condition that a.id is null (no match found in table a).

For deletes, use

```
DELETE FROM table2
WHERE table1_id not in (select id from table1)
```

Comment: @cyberwiki can't be `LEFT JOIN AND WHERE`  replaced with RIGHT JOIN??

Comment: @diEcho WHERE is required to remove those that match. RIGHT and LEFT only depends on where you place the tables.

Comment: @Cyberwiki - Is it possible to perform delete action using the same query?I tried .. DELETE FROM table2 b LEFT JOIN table1 a ON b.table1_id = a.id WHERE a.id is null but I get an myql error in phpmyadmin?? What am I doing wrong?